# How do I select multiple bullet lists within word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to find all instances of bulleted lists within a large selection of a word doc and assign them a style as per our company branding.

I have gotten pretty close, the following Macro selects the first line in the first bulleted list in the selection and assigns it the style I require.

I just need some help getting it to select all the bullets in the doc.

```
Sub findbullets22()
    'findbullets22 Macro
    Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
    With Selection
        For Each oPara In .Paragraphs
            If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = _
            WdListType.wdListBullet Then
                oPara.Range.Select
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("List Paragraph")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? You have to set style inside the loop and not outside the loop.

```
Sub findbullets22()
    Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph

    With Selection
        For Each oPara In .Paragraphs
            If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet Then
                oPara.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("List Paragraph")
                DoEvents
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth - thanks so much for your help I put this into my document and what happens now is the first two bulleted lists get styled and the rest get deleted.

Comment: Any idea why this might be happening? Thanks so much for any insight you can provide :)

Comment: The clue is here `With Selection` If the bullets were not in the selection then they will be ignored ;)

Comment: They all are as they are within a table and I selected the entire table. It's so confusing I can't think of any reason why this would happen. Does it change my selection when it finds a bullet?

Comment: Hi Siddharth I found out why those particular bullets were being ignored its because they were sitting inside a table that was sitting inside a table cell.

Comment: Any idea how I could select a table thats within a table - it would be fantastic to know as I need to change the column widths on these also...

Comment: Are all bullets inside 1 cell or 1 bullet per cell?

Comment: All bullets inside one cell - but the cell is sitting in a larger table cell

Comment: The document is laid out within a large table so all text and tables reside in a table within a table if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't :) Can you upload a sample document in wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: I actually found the answer to this query so I'll post it here just incase anyone else wants to know:`code`Dim oTable as Table 
 
For Each oTable in ThisDocument.Tables(1).Tables 
 
    'Do something with oTable - like 
    'setting the width of the first column 
    oTable.Columns(1).Width = 60 
 
Next

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981981/select-a-all-tables-within-table-using-word-macro :)

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
With seletion
     For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
         If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet Then
            oPara.Range.Select
            oPara.style = ActiveDocument.styles("List Paragraph")
         End If
     Next
End With
```

Comment: This explains the bulletlist in document anywhere is changed to "List Paragraph" style. As what nicemanda wants for.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a macro to select all bullets:

```
Sub SelectBullets()
On Error Resume Next
Dim Para As Word.Paragraph
With ActiveDocument
    .DeleteAllEditableRanges (-1)
    For Each Para In .Paragraphs
        If Para.Range.ListFormat.ListType > 0 Then
            Para.Range.Editors.Add (-1)
        End If
    Next
    .SelectAllEditableRanges (-1)
    .DeleteAllEditableRanges (-1)
End With
End Sub
```

Once selected, you can uniformly modify all bullets.

Para.Range.ListFormat.ListType > 0 - this command specifies that each and every type of bullet or numbered list is to be selected.
Para.Range.Editors.Add (-1) - this command adds the relevant selection to range
.SelectAllEditableRanges (-1) - this command selects all ranges added

For additional useful word macros, please visit my video available at the following link
https://youtu.be/p_ZhufliFw8

Regards,
Suril Mehta